# SQL Server---how to group by a column that is declared in CASE statement in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am having a problem on group by the column [rating]. When I execute it, it gives "Invalid column name 'rate'".

Can anyone help me ? THANKS!!

```
SELECT
     ......
   CASE
         WHEN level_1 = 'Corporate'
         THEN 
            CASE
            WHEN ssr.rating = 'A' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'A[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp A'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'AA' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp AA'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'BBB' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp BBB'

            ELSE NULL
        END

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Provincial'
            THEN 'Prov'

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Federal'
            THEN 'Canada'

       ELSE NULL
   END AS rating,
     ......
  SUM(...)
     .......
FROM....
GROUP BY rating
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sub-query or repeat it as Richard has mentioned or use a `Common-Table-Expression` which is more readable in my opinion:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT CASE 
                  WHEN level_1 = 'Corporate' THEN 
                    CASE 
                      WHEN ssr.rating = 'A' 
                            OR ssr.rating LIKE 'A[+-]' THEN 'Corp A' 
                      WHEN ssr.rating = 'AA' 
                            OR ssr.rating LIKE 'AA[+-]' THEN 'Corp AA' 
                      WHEN ssr.rating = 'BBB' 
                            OR ssr.rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]' THEN 'Corp BBB' 
                      ELSE NULL 
                    END 
                  WHEN level_1 = 'Government' 
                       AND level_2 = 'Provincial' THEN 'Prov' 
                  WHEN level_1 = 'Government' 
                       AND level_2 = 'Federal' THEN 'Canada' 
                  ELSE NULL 
                END AS rating -- other columns ...
         FROM   dbo.tablename) 
SELECT cte.*, 
       Sum(col)AS ColSum 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY rating
```

Comment: ＋１  [`WITH common_table_expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175972%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) being the means to DRY when doing `CASEGROUP`.

Answer (score 0):

Either make it a derived table (aka subquery) or repeat the entire expression (don't worry SQL Server will calculate it once and use it many times).

In your case, it looks easier to just repeat the CASE expression.

```
SELECT
     ......
   CASE
         WHEN level_1 = 'Corporate'
         THEN 
            CASE
            WHEN ssr.rating = 'A' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'A[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp A'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'AA' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp AA'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'BBB' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp BBB'

            ELSE NULL
        END

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Provincial'
            THEN 'Prov'

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Federal'
            THEN 'Canada'

       ELSE NULL
   END AS rating,
     ......
  SUM(...)
     .......
FROM....
GROUP BY CASE
         WHEN level_1 = 'Corporate'
         THEN 
            CASE
            WHEN ssr.rating = 'A' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'A[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp A'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'AA' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp AA'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'BBB' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp BBB'

            ELSE NULL
        END

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Provincial'
            THEN 'Prov'

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Federal'
            THEN 'Canada'

       ELSE NULL
   END
```

Comment: ... or use a `common-table-expression`.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works, but I still don't understand why we have to repeat the entire expression in GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Tim I mentioned derived table, which could be by way of CTE as you have mentioned, or just a regular subquery.

Comment: I'm putting this into python. I think there is a way to take the case statement as a template, and then insert template parameter back into the code in order to eliminate repetition of code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I find that the simplest way is simply to use subqueries:

```
select rating, .  .
from (SELECT
     ......
   CASE
         WHEN level_1 = 'Corporate'
         THEN 
            CASE
            WHEN ssr.rating = 'A' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'A[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp A'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'AA' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp AA'

            WHEN ssr.rating = 'BBB' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]'
            THEN 'Corp BBB'

            ELSE NULL
        END

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Provincial'
            THEN 'Prov'

            WHEN level_1 = 'Government' AND level_2 = 'Federal'
            THEN 'Canada'

       ELSE NULL
   END AS rating,
   *
 from . . .
) t
group by rating;
```

This works across all databases, including MySQL and Access.  The downside is that some databases treat a subquery as a derived table, and actually save out the intermediate result.  No accounting for bad SQL engine implementations.  In such cases, if you want to avoid that overhead, you need to repeat the case in the `group by` statement.  And, there do exist databases that will accept the `rating` in the `group by`, but very few.